# How can I refer to people who do not own a bicycle with a single term?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a paper and I need a term to refer to people who do not own a bicycle, so I don't need to write 'people who do not own a bicycle' every time. What is the right option?

- non bicycle-owners
- non-bicycle-owners
- non-bicycle owners
- bicycle non-owners

Comment: For more information on how to use hyphens correctly, please refer to [this article by The Writer](http://www.thewriter.com/what-we-think/style-guide/to-hyphenate-or-not-to-hyphenate/).

Comment: One time you say 'people who do not own a bicycle', then you can refer to them as 'they', 'those people', 'the bicycleless-people' etc.!

Comment: Single term, single word - _the bikeless_

Comment: "Non-cyclist" gets 21MM hits on Google, although that refers to  people who don't engage in the hobby, not owners per se.

Comment: "Bike-deprived" is the term I'd use.

Comment: car owners versus non-owners; bicycle owners versus non-owners. You don't need to repeat the name of the vehicle.....

Answer (score 1):

The correct one would be "non-bicycle-owners".

What would we call those who own bicycles?  "Bicycle-owners".

Naturally, those who do not own bicycles can be called "non-bicycle-owners".

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with this “natural” progression. If a _bicycle owner_ owns a bicycle, then wouldn’t a _non-bicycle owner_ own something that **isn’t** a bicycle? (I’m not saying you’re wrong, but I do think this answer would be improved with some citations showing this construct being used in the way that you describe.)

Comment: @J.R. The problem is that the use of the first hyphen is ambiguous. I *do* agree with *bicycle owner* versus *(non) bicycle owner*. The only question is how the introduction of *non* should affect the styling of the phrase. Common wisdom would say to rephrase the sentence to avoid the problem . . .

Comment: I am with @J.R. on this. A non-bicycle-owner owns a non-bicycle. Whatever that is. Whether or not they also own a bicycle on top of that, is entirely up to them. English just doesn't build negation like this. If you don't play the piano, you say "I am not a piano player". You don't say "I'm a non-piano-player". If you are not a math professor, you don't say "I'm a non-math-professor". If you don't work for Amazon, you don't say "I'm a non-Amazon-employee". If you don't have a subscription to the New Yorker, you don't say "I'm a non-New-Yorker-subscriber".

Comment: bike owners versus non-owners. In English, ***if you have already said bike owners, non-owners is enough.***  You don't need to repeat the word bike, in context. Also, those hyphens are wrong.  In a table with statistics, non-bicycle:  car 
 or truck owners, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Bicycle non-owners.

Unintended semantics: if you have bicycles and non-bicycles, then also bicycle owners and non-bicycle owners.

Intended semantics: if you have owners and non-owners, then also bicycle owners and bicycle non-owners.

Admittedly, if I saw "non-bicycle owners" in print, then I would probably read it as it were "bicycle non-owners" unless the context had (for some reason) drawn attention to the class of all objects which are not bicycles. However, as a phrase, "non-bicycle owners" lacks precision.

@NigelJ's "the bikeless" is probably better, but that isn't what you asked.

Answer (score -1):

I have no dictionary authority for this, and it's a bit flippant, but in some contexts the ***unbiked*** or ***un-biked*** would work.

Comment: Sounds like something you’d find in bicycle jousting.

Comment: How about the biking and non-biking with ing?

Comment: @Lambie the question is about possession, not use; someone could be a *biking* individual without owning a bike, or temporarily *non-biking* due to injury.

Comment: Yes, right. But biking is imaginable, biked is not.

Answer (score -1):

**People who do not own a bicycle** = ***People sans bicycles***!

**[Sans (preposition) : without](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sans)**

*Anyone sans shirt will not be allowed in the restaurant.* ([M-W Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sans))

Comment: +1 just because of the creativity. However, you can *own* a bicycle but not actually have it with you at a given time. In other words, you can be both a bicycle owner as well as *sans* bicycle.

Comment: Such answers help, but one can assume that OP would prefer a "non" construct.